# Razor Mediator for Web 8

Tags: web8, razormediator, installation

Does Tridion Razor Mediator Supports SDL Web 8.
I am able to download the installer from the below path,but its in beta version.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6hZ-cambftrV25ZLU5QTnJWSmM
Can you Please share me the latest Installer information.

Comment: Razor Mediator supporting 8.5? Pls let me know. but web 8 its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is supported in Web 8.  You can download the latest version here, http://razor-mediator-4-tridion.googlecode.com/files/RazorMediatorInstaller_v1.3.3.1.msi

There is also a nice presentation about debugging Razor Templates in Visual Studio at the Tridion Developer Summit this year here:https://vimeo.com/177712049

Comment: Looks like above link not exist, it's moved to https://github.com/alex-klock/razor-mediator-4-tridion/releases

Answer (score 1):

The Razor mediator integrates with Web 8 using supported APIs which have had no breaking changes since they were introduced. This means that you should have a good expectation that it works fine with SDL Web 8.

You have asked if it is supported. The Razor mediator is an open source project, and is not supported by SDL. There is support available from the community, but no "support agreement". The community support is usually good, however there is always the chance that you'll have to roll your sleeves up and look at the code yourself. Having said that, the code should be readily understood by a competent .NET developer.